# How to merge multiple Excel files into one sheet and keep the formatting of the files in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

My goal is to merge multiple excel files into one sheet of data and still keep the format of the files that have been merged in the new file. I have tried a workaround with Pandas and openpyxl but right now only the first file gets the correct formatting and the rest of the files are then merged without formatting. Here is my current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for root, dir, filenames in os.walk(dir_containing_files):
    for file in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file_path), ignore_index=True) 
 
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

source_wb = load_workbook(file_path)
source_sheet = source_wb.active

for row in source_sheet.rows:
    for cell in row:
        # Read and assign formatting to new file
        new_cell = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column,
            value= cell.value)
        if cell.has_style:
            new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
            new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
            new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
            new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
            new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
            new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)


wb.save('merge.xlsx')
print('merge complete')
```

Comment: It seems you’re only loading the style of the last file onto the rows of the first file. You need to put the parsing of `source_wb` inside your loop over files (where `file_path` is defined). You’ll probably also need to shift the style assignments by the number of rows previously appended to your output file.

Comment: If you are merging Excel files it really makes **no** sense to use Pandas to drive openpyxl. Do it directly in openpyxl and it will be faster and easier to control.

Comment: in openpyxl you can get/change the style. see: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with openpyxl 3.1.2 going in to each file that i want to merge and keeping track of the row with the variable row_number

def merge_delete_files(number_of_files):
# Create a new workbook to store the merged data
merged_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
merged_ws = merged_wb.active

```
excel_files = []

# Create the list of files
for i in range(int(number_of_files)):
    excel_files.append("Excels_folder/smaller_file_" + str(i + 1) + ".xlsx")

# Specify the destination sheet in the merged workbook
destination_sheet = merged_wb.active

row_number = 0
# Loop through each Excel file to merge
for file_path in excel_files:
    # Open the source workbook
    source_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

    # Select the desired sheet from the source workbook
    source_sheet = source_wb.active

    # Loop through rows and cells in the source sheet
    for row in source_sheet.iter_rows():
        row_number += 1
        for cell in row:
            # Write the cell value in the destination sheet keeping the source formatting
            string = cell.column_letter + str(row_number)
            destination_sheet[string].value = cell.value
            destination_sheet[string].font = copy(cell.font)
            destination_sheet[string].alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
            destination_sheet[string].number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
            destination_sheet[string].protection = copy(cell.protection)
            destination_sheet[string].fill = copy(cell.fill)
            destination_sheet[string].border = copy(cell.border)

# Save the merged workbook to a file
merged_wb.save('merged.xlsx')

print('Excel files merged successfully.')
```